# How to get Node Title and description when nid is avaiable?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

In Drupal 7 I am using following code in *Global: PHP*.

```
$data = message_load($row->mid);

if (isset($data->field_related_flag)){
  $fid = $data->field_related_flag['und'][0]['target_id'];
  $ftype = $data->field_flagged_node_type['und'][0]['value'];
  $flag = db_query('SELECT f.entity_id content_id, f.fid flag_id, flag.title type FROM flagging f INNER JOIN flag ON flag.fid = f.fid WHERE flagging_id = :val_fid', array(':val_fid' => $fid))-> fetchAssoc();
  $flag['content_type'] = $ftype;
  return json_encode($flag);
}
```

And from this code, I get the following output:

```
'related_flag' => '{"content_id":"410","flag_id":"1","type":"like","content_type":"event"}',
```

Here `"content_id":"410"` is the node ID.

Now I need to get the node title, description, and other fields. Can anyone please tell me what code I should write to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily load the node using `$node = node_load($nid);`

Hoever it can be a bit tricky to get the values you want, so I recommend [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). They are part of the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module and they allow you to access node variables like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node_wrapper->title->value();
$node_wrapper->field_description->value();
```

At the bottom of the linked Entity metadata wrapper page is a section on *Debugging or introspecting wrappers*, you can use that to find all available fields and their names.

Comment: Do I need to create another PHP field in view and enter this $node = node_load($nid); to load node ? Can you please explain it bit more. If you can give me complete example on how I should get the Title in output ?

Comment: No need for a separate PHP block. You can append to what you have. Your question didn't mention output. Pleae update the question to express what you want to achieve. I get the feeling you can do this much easier with views relationships.

Comment: The output I am getting from the above code is 
` 'related_flag' => '{"content_id":"410","flag_id":"1","type":"like","content_type":"event"}',`
as I am getting Content_id, I just want to get title of this content_id ?

Comment: Extracting the nid from that line is basic PHP knowledge. But as I said it can be done with views relationships. Just explain (edit your question) what you want to achieve in the end.